# FileSystem partition is ignored

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, disk, disk-usage, home-directory

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my computer and I created 4 partitions.

For some reason the main partition containing 460GB is not allocated to the home disk space.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/L28jq.png

When I run `df -H` in the terminal I get the following results:

```
udev            7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  2.5M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p1   19G   17G  671M  97% /
tmpfs           7.8G   58M  7.7G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0      128K  128K     0 100% /snap/bare/5
/dev/loop2      219M  219M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/77
/dev/loop3      213M  213M     0 100% /snap/code/89
/dev/loop4      249M  249M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/99
/dev/loop5      111M  111M     0 100% /snap/core/12725
/dev/loop6       66M   66M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1519
/dev/loop7       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2128
/dev/loop8      190M  190M     0 100% /snap/postman/172
/dev/loop9       83M   83M     0 100% /snap/discord/132
/dev/loop11      62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/1361
/dev/loop12     192M  192M     0 100% /snap/postman/173
/dev/loop13      44M   44M     0 100% /snap/snapd/14978
/dev/nvme0n1p3  976M  5.3M  970M   1% /boot/efi
/dev/loop14      56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2284
/dev/loop15     248M  248M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/87
/dev/loop16     165M  165M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161
/dev/loop17     219M  219M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72
/dev/nvme0n1p4  422G   41G  360G  11% /home
/dev/loop18      83M   83M     0 100% /snap/discord/131
/dev/loop19     296M  296M     0 100% /snap/vlc/2344
/dev/loop20      51M   51M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/547
/dev/loop21      66M   66M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1515
/dev/loop22      55M   55M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/558
tmpfs           1.6G  3.4M  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/loop23     213M  213M     0 100% /snap/code/90
/dev/loop1       62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/1376
tmpfs           1.6G   84K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1001
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is a new installation, you should probably start over.  This partition scheme is not viable.

25GB is the minimum system requirement for Ubuntu Desktop.  You only allocated 19GB for your root file system. This isn't enough and your file system is already 97% full.

You set up `/home` on a separate partition. Even though `/home` is mounted under `/` your root file system cannot use that space because that space resides in a different partition.

You might want to reconsider your plan to create extra partitions. The default installation settings will put your entire installation on one partition.  This is the best configuration for the majority of Ubuntu users. There is no need to create any additional partitions.

A separate `/home` partition isn't required and may not actually be that useful, depending on your use case.

It's not clear for what reason you made the other two partitions, but you might want to know that you don't need a swap partition either, since Ubuntu has switched to using a swapfile by default.

If your only reason for partitioning is *organization*, I would caution against using partitions for this purpose.  Partitions place rigid, inflexible limitations on how your system can use the available space. **Folders** do a better job for organization. Those extra partitions would be mounted as folders anyway, as you can currently see with `/home`.

Comment: That's a really nice succinct answer!